# C compiler (gcc) converts the int to float or float to int in 100.0 == 100?

Tags: c

I cannot figure out which way it goes. It seems like casting it into an int would make more sense because of the whole float point issue but like I said, I am not sure. Does anyone know?

Comment: It will convert int `100` to double `100.0f`.

Comment: no I mean you can run the comparison of 100.0 == 100 but the compiler will automatically do a cast. What does it cast into what?

Comment: Read up on _arithmetic conversions_. You get a `double` here, as jsn said.

Comment: what if he write `100 == 100.0`? a `int` right?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: No. `100.0` is still a float. That's why you put the `.0` on the end.

Comment: So the conversion isn't from left to right?

Comment: @LoicFaure-Lacroix No. It probably does convert from one side to another, but it looks at the types.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix No, it's type driven.

Comment: for a homework question, I like this question

Comment: @jsn: I know this is purely pedantic, but sometimes it matters.  100.0f is a float (single precision), not a double.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I know this is purely pedantic, but sometimes it matters.  100.0 is a double (double precision), not a float.  100.0f would be a float.

Comment: @sfstewman: The term "float" can refer to any floating point format. The C/C++ type "double" is a double-precision float, which is a type of float. If I could edit my comment though, I'd change it to "is still a type of float" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (100.1 == 100)
        printf("Must be integer compare\n");
    else
        printf("Must be floating point compare\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, think about things like `int i = 10; float j = 100.5 + i;` or `100.2 == 100`. You don't want it to be done with integers!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "the usual arithmetic conversion" make sense for both arithmetic and for comparisons.  The range of floating point numbers is much greater than the range of integers.  Single-precision floats have 8-bits of exponent, and can represent numbers with magnitudes as large as 2^127 (~10^38).  Double-precision has an 11-bit exponent, and can represent even larger magnitudes.  The largest number that a 64-bit unsigned int can represent is 2^65-1 (less than 10^20).

Answer (score 5):

It's listed in 6.3.1.8 under "the usual arithmetic conversions".

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double,
> the other operand  is  converted,  without  change  of  type  domain,
> to  a  type  whose corresponding real type is double

And 6.5.9 spells it for `==`:

> If  both  of  the  operands  have  arithmetic  type,  the  usual
> arithmetic  conversions  are performed.

#### EDIT

I am citing C11 N1570.

Comment: I find it humorous how you site the sections but don't mention what document you're talking about.